# Django admin sites - location of admin.py

Tags: django, django-admin

I am writing django project which has several small apps. I want to use default admin site, so my admin.py will be very simple. Unfortunatelly it doesn't work if I put it to project directory - it has to be in app directory. Now I have two options:

- Put one admin.py in one of app's directory - it will work but it's logically not correct
- Put several admin.py files in each app directory (containing only models from certain app)

Is there some way to force django to look for this file in project root directory?

Comment: Why would you not want to do it the proper way, ie your second option? What would be the benefit?

Comment: I want to keep my project tree as clean as possible. And also it also means writing the same 'code' few times... at least importing 'admin'.

Comment: the normal procedure is to have one admin.py in each app directory. if you think that this is cluttering up your project tree.... well, um.... Think of it like this - the point is that each app is a self contained unit that could potentially be used by a different project. Therefore each `admin.py` needs to be seperate. And seriously... `from django.contrib import admin` - that's really not code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the file in your "default" app (the one that was created when you created your project).  Then you can import models from other apps and use them in that single admin.py file.  For example, the file below would work across a default app and "Courses", "Forum" apps.

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from models import UserProfile, Sponsor
from courses.models import Course
from forum.models import ForumTopic
admin.site.register(UserProfile)
admin.site.register(Sponsor)
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("code", "name",)}

admin.site.register(Course, CourseAdmin)


class ForumTopicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}

admin.site.register(ForumTopic, ForumTopicAdmin)
```